# How to store the output of "count" function in a list of dataframes

Tags: r, loops, dplyr

I have a list of data frames like this:

```
list1 <- list(df1 = data.frame(animal = 1:10, specie = c("rabbit", "rabbit", "rabbit", "rabbit", "pig", "pig", "pig", "chicken", "chicken", "chicken")),
                  df2 = data.frame(animal = 1:10, specie = c("rabbit", "rabbit", "pig", "pig", "pig", "pig", "pig", "pig", "chicken", "chicken")))
```

From each DF in the list1 I am trying to get a DF summarizing the number of fields in the column "specie". I am using the function `count` of the package `dplyr`. Then I am trying to store them in a second list of DFs (list2).  I am using a loop like this:

```
   list2 <- list()
    for (i in 1:length(list1)) {
      list2[paste(names(list1[i]))] = count(list1[[i]], specie)
    }
```

I was expecting my list2 had two DFs like these:

```
    > df1
       specie n
    1 chicken 3
    2     pig 3
    3   rabbit 4
    > df2
       specie n
    1 chicken 2
    2     pig 6
    3   rabbit 2
```

Instead I am getting this message: `number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement lengthnumber of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length` Also, in the list2 I am getting two vectors instead of DFs. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will work:

```r
list2 <- list()
for (i in 1:length(list1)) {
  list2[[i]] <- dplyr::count(list1[[i]], specie)
}
```

Also:

```r
list2 <- lapply(list1, function(x) dplyr::count(x, specie))
```

Comment: The second option with `lapply` worked well. The first one did not work, same issue! I wonder why? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
#library(tidyverse)
purrr:map(list1, ~dplyr::count(.x, specie))


$df1
   specie n
1 chicken 3
2     pig 3
3  rabbit 4

$df2
   specie n
1 chicken 2
2     pig 6
3  rabbit 2
```